# Click in an html tag and display another that is initially hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

Each `<p>` are hidden on initial load and I want to click on the `<h3>` then want the p-tag to show using Javascript.

I have a section in my HTML that looks as follow

```html
<div id="bio-sections">
  <div id="history">
    <h3 onclick="openFunction()">My History</h3>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga alias hic officia dolor quidem maiores quasi architecto veritatis obcaecati debitis, rem suscipit quo blanditiis perspiciatis deleniti id a rerum quae!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="schooling">
    <h3>My Schooling</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In iure distinctio voluptatum non quia maxime numquam amet eum at, quo ut iusto est quos hic placeat. Repudiandae dolorem cupiditate illo.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="work">
    <h3>My Work experience</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam dolor nemo nostrum consequuntur. Tempora, quia nobis eligendi, labore porro natus voluptates nam, consectetur corporis vitae eius hic sed ea earum.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="hobbies">
    <h3>My Hobbies</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor perspiciatis ipsam suscipit voluptas ab distinctio a doloribus, dolorem officia iure nemo qui incidunt soluta dolores ratione saepe. In, mollitia! Voluptatem!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is how do you reference the following div (or in this case p-tag) given the H3 you pressed?

If you press the H3 under `#history` then only that p-tag must show and the same with the other divs. But how do you do this in Javascript without duplicating code with different id's or classes.

Comment: Share your JS code too

Comment: Given the clicked element you can use [Node.nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) in vanilla JS or [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) in Jquery

Answer (score 1):

My approach avoid the use of inline JS inside HTML, which is a bad practice.

Select all `<h3>` that are clickable and should open the `<p>` tags, then add the listener to them all.

Now, all you need is the function using `this`, that refers to the clicked `h3`, get it's sibling element, check if it is displaying or not, and do the toggle.

See below code

```js
openFunction = function(ev) {
  let pTagElem = this.nextElementSibling

  if (pTagElem.style.display == "inline") {
    pTagElem.style.display = "none"
  } else {
    pTagElem.style.display = "inline"
  }
}

//select all <h3> that should be clickable (inside bio-sections divs)
let h3s = document.querySelectorAll("#bio-sections div h3")

//add the listener to them all
for (let h3 of h3s) {
  h3.onclick = openFunction
}
```

```css
#bio-sections div p {
  display: none
}

#bio-sections div h3 {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div id="bio-sections">
  <div id="history">
    <h3>My History</h3>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga alias hic officia dolor quidem maiores quasi architecto veritatis obcaecati debitis, rem suscipit quo blanditiis perspiciatis deleniti id a rerum quae!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="schooling">
    <h3>My Schooling</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In iure distinctio voluptatum non quia maxime numquam amet eum at, quo ut iusto est quos hic placeat. Repudiandae dolorem cupiditate illo.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="work">
    <h3>My Work experience</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam dolor nemo nostrum consequuntur. Tempora, quia nobis eligendi, labore porro natus voluptates nam, consectetur corporis vitae eius hic sed ea earum.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="hobbies">
    <h3>My Hobbies</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor perspiciatis ipsam suscipit voluptas ab distinctio a doloribus, dolorem officia iure nemo qui incidunt soluta dolores ratione saepe. In, mollitia! Voluptatem!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript parameters like this, and move the id into the `p` tag

```
<div>
    <h3 onclick="openFunction('history')">My History</h3>    
    <p id="history">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga alias hic officia dolor quidem maiores quasi architecto veritatis obcaecati debitis, rem suscipit quo blanditiis perspiciatis deleniti id a rerum quae!</p>
</div>

<script>
    function openFunction(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).show()
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closest()` and delegation.

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#bio-sections");

container.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  const parentSectionDiv = event.target.closest(".section");
  if (parentSectionDiv !== null) {
    parentSectionDiv.querySelector("p").classList.remove("hidden");
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /> -->
    <title>Sign in & Sign up Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bio-sections">
      <div id="history" class="section">
        <h3>My History</h3>
        <p class="hidden">
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga alias
          hic officia dolor quidem maiores quasi architecto veritatis obcaecati
          debitis, rem suscipit quo blanditiis perspiciatis deleniti id a rerum
          quae!
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="schooling" class="section">
        <h3>My Schooling</h3>
        <p class="hidden">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In iure
          distinctio voluptatum non quia maxime numquam amet eum at, quo ut
          iusto est quos hic placeat. Repudiandae dolorem cupiditate illo.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="work" class="section">
        <h3>My Work experience</h3>
        <p class="hidden">
          Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam
          dolor nemo nostrum consequuntur. Tempora, quia nobis eligendi, labore
          porro natus voluptates nam, consectetur corporis vitae eius hic sed ea
          earum.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="hobbies" class="section">
        <h3>My Hobbies</h3>
        <p class="hidden">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor
          perspiciatis ipsam suscipit voluptas ab distinctio a doloribus,
          dolorem officia iure nemo qui incidunt soluta dolores ratione saepe.
          In, mollitia! Voluptatem!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how stable your HTML is, but if you are confident it remains like that you don't need to change it and can on the click get the p element.

There's several ways of doing this. This snippet gets the common parent and the first p element in it.

```js
function openFunction() {
  console.log(event.target);
  console.log(event.target.parentElement.querySelector('p:first-of-type'));
}
```

```html
<div id="bio-sections">
  <div id="history">
    <h3 onclick="openFunction()">My History</h3>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga alias hic officia dolor quidem maiores quasi architecto veritatis obcaecati debitis, rem suscipit quo blanditiis perspiciatis deleniti id a rerum quae!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="schooling">
    <h3>My Schooling</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In iure distinctio voluptatum non quia maxime numquam amet eum at, quo ut iusto est quos hic placeat. Repudiandae dolorem cupiditate illo.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="work">
    <h3>My Work experience</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam dolor nemo nostrum consequuntur. Tempora, quia nobis eligendi, labore porro natus voluptates nam, consectetur corporis vitae eius hic sed ea earum.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="hobbies">
    <h3>My Hobbies</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor perspiciatis ipsam suscipit voluptas ab distinctio a doloribus, dolorem officia iure nemo qui incidunt soluta dolores ratione saepe. In, mollitia! Voluptatem!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```